# Django: Quizapp with Question and Answer Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I would like to create a Quiz app with Django.
Where the Questions can be stored in a DB and more users can add more questions in Admin.
and each question can have an answer from the user input.

This is a basic version of what I tried so far,
**Simple example of My Models:**

QuestionModel

- ID
- question
- author

AnswerModel

- ID
- Answer
- question_id
- author

So, When I create an AnswerForm():
it shows the form, but the question shows up as a dropdown instead of labels.
and it is not creating fields for each question. It just creates one input field and a dropdown for the question.
I know it does that because I have question_id as FK in the Answer Model.

Is there a better way to get this done?
I am new to Django

Here is a screenshot of what I am expecting
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not good in django, but I think you can use these structure:

Question Model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60,)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=200)
```

Answer Model:

```
 class Answer(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     answer = models.TextField()         
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     post = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In your views add:

```
class My_Answer(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Answer
    fields = ['answer']
    template_name = 'answer.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('#Redirecting User To The Dashboard')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        result = super().form_valid(form)
        return result
```

In your Urls add:

```
    path('question/<int:pk>/answer/', views.My_Answer.as_view(), name='answer'),
```

Add this to your answer template:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
               <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                 {% csrf_token %}  
                 {{ form | crispy }}
                 <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Comment: Hi @adamu, Thank you for ur response but this doesn't answer my question.
I am adding a screenshot to support my question